# Adding a white outline surrounding the image (irregular shape)

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, image-conversion

I have several image and want to make it as a sticker. I want to add a white outline border surrounding the image. (not the rectangular one, need the one follow the shape of the image)

Any software allow me to do that easily and if possible can do in batch mode?

Comment: On what OS? And what is your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). It's free open-source software.

Use the magic wand tool to select the parts of the image you want to surround. Then Select > Grow, to add the width of the border (e.g., 4px). Then Select > Border (e.g., 4px), to create a border selection. Next, pick white as the color you want to use with the fill tool (the bucket) that you can fill with white.

On the bucket tool, you'll want "fill whole selection" and "FG color fill" selected. The put the cross-hairs of the bucket cursor inside the 4px border selection and left-click.

You might need to go into the image with the pencil tool to touch up any sharp angles with white, but it'll get the job done.

[image: White Border added with GIMP using Magic Wand selection, Grow Selection, Add Border, and Fill.]